# FlatList is re-rendering items everytime screen is scrolled

Tags: react-native

I have a list of 300 items. I'm using FlatList to render the items.

**ISSUE :**

- List items re-rendering when I scroll the screen. Even when I have wrapped the component in React.memo.

I tried to optimise the list by tweaking the `windowSize`, `maxToRenderPerBatch` but the issue still persist.

You can check the code in below sandbox link.

Thankyou in advance !

https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-dhawan-i4d51h?file=/src/App.js

Below is the code snippet

```
const data = [
{
    id: 1,
    first_name: "Shaina",
    last_name: "Osorio",
    email: "sosorio0@a8.net"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    first_name: "Ania",
    last_name: "Cotilard",
    email: "acotilard1@about.me"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    first_name: "Hagen",
    last_name: "Lisciandri",
    email: "hlisciandri2@nature.com"
  }
]
```

```js
const isEqual = (prev, next) => {
  return true;
};

const RenderItem = React.memo((props) => {
  const { id, first_name, email } = props;
  console.log("id >>> ", id);

  return (
    <View
      style={{
        padding: 5,
        backgroundColor: "lightblue",
        marginVertical: 3
      }}
    >
      <Text>First Name : {first_name}</Text>
      <Text>Email : {email}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}, isEqual);

function App() {

  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <RenderItem
            id={item.id}
            first_name={item.first_name}
            email={item.email}
          />
        )}
        initialNumToRender={15}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={15}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Did you try using `<Profiler>` wrapper instead of `<View>`?https://it.reactjs.org/docs/profiler.html

Comment: Instead of passing a arrow function in keyExtractor, pass a function reference that does not change, similar for renderItem.

Comment: @jayshah I tried it, but it's not working.

Answer (score 1):

In your example, you are logging inside your renderItem, so when a new element comes into the rendered area, it is logged. This happens when you scroll. But this doesn't mean that the whole list will be re-rendered. Just place a conosle.log directly in the component that hosts the list, and you'll see that it's only rendered once, unlike the renderItem, which is rendered every time a new item is created by a scroll.

```
const App = ()=> {
  console.log("Entire List Rerendered");
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1 }}>
      <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem={rendering}
        initialNumToRender={5}
        maxToRenderPerBatch={5}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
```

Flashlist might help, because it recycles renderItems and doesn't destroy them like Flatlist does. But you should test that better.

Also check out this attempt to visually explain your console logs.

[image]

Comment: The list item is wrapped with `React.memo`, then why on scroll I'm seeing log for the items which were rendered before?

Comment: Flatlist renders 10 viewports on top, 10 on the bottom, and one in between. If your list exceeds this range, new render items will be created as you scroll, while others will be removed. You can test this by setting the window size to a very high value, say 1000, and you will see that no render item is created/deleted (no console.logs any more) as they are all rendered. For a web application this may not be a problem, but for a mobile application this can cause significant performance issues. So as a rule of thumb, you should keep the windowSize as small as possible.

Comment: https://reactnative.dev/docs/optimizing-flatlist-configuration

Comment: if the answer helped feel free to accept it @YogeshTripathi

Answer (score 0):

Check out FlashList by Shopify they are saying that it is much more optimized than Flatlist. maybe it can meet your needs. no harm in trying: [Click Here](https://shopify.github.io/flash-list/docs/)

```js
    import React from "react";
    import { View, Text, StatusBar } from "react-native";
    import { FlashList } from "@shopify/flash-list";
    
    const DATA = [
      {
        title: "First Item",
      },
      {
        title: "Second Item",
      },
    ];
    
    const MyList = () => {
      return (
        <FlashList
          data={DATA}
          renderItem={({ item }) => <Text>{item.title}</Text>}
          estimatedItemSize={200}
        />
      );
    };
```